# QVector Append truncating/rounding values

Tags: c++, qt, truncation, qvector, qdebug

I am using QVector.append to append a double to QVector. Using my debugger, I can see that the double has a value of 40.783333499999998, however, the QVector values are rounded to 40.7833. Again, I see this on my debugger, not using qDebug so I'm relatively sure that the error is in the storage/appending function and not some other loss of precision elsewhere in my code. It's very important that the vector contains the full value. My code is below. In the debugger I can see that both the DictionaryOfValues and the iterator contains full precision, but the dataMatrix value is rounded. I can't seem to find where this error occurs. I'm using QT 5.2.1 MinGW 32 bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In this code, DictionaryOfValues is a QMap and dataMatrix is a QMap>

```
    QMapIterator<QString,double> i(DictionaryOfValues);
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        i.next();
        dataMatrix[i.key()].append(i.value());
    }
```

Comment: or it has to do with how the debugger formats the variables

Comment: Try using `std::vector` and compare the results to `QVector`.  In theory, these data structures only copy variables, they don't affect the content of their data.

Comment: I've thought about that, but every value is formatted as a double. I would think that means they're all treated the same, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that's because of the way debugger formats `QVector` values. The Actual value in the vector is not rounded at all. You can test it by checking the output of `qDebug` using this simple example :

```
double a = 40.783333499999998;

QVector<double> vec;
vec.append(a);

qDebug() <<"double :"<<qSetRealNumberPrecision(17) <<a;
qDebug() <<"Vector: "<< qSetRealNumberPrecision(17) << vec;
```

You can see that that the two outputs are the same :

> double : 40.783333499999998
>   Vector: QVector(40.783333499999998)

The default precision value is 6. You can change it by `qSetRealNumberPrecision` when using `qDebug`.